# Spring Integration : How to know whether two and more interfaces are succeed and allow business logic go on next step?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am making some complext integration for other system and using Spring integration.

```
What I want to achieve is like following.
System  ::  A -> B -> C
① A -> B there are each seven integrations. 
② B have to check whether or not it recevies all 7 integration datas. 
③ then B decide to send summary data that extracted from those datas.
```

At ②, I can't find the way to implement this with spring integraiton.  at the first glance, I thought I can make it simply with aggregator pattern.  But now, I can't be sure about the traffic and how to make the logic to check.

please give some advice for making these things with spring integration. I want to avoid the way to implement with hardcoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `release-strategy-expression="size() == 7"`. If you need more sophistication than that, then you will need to implement a custom release strategy.